# How do I change design to prevent retrieving tickets by passing through 4 tables & multiple nested for loops

Tags: java, mysql, performance, database-design

The code I use is working fine. It takes little longer to retrieve and display the data. I feel the table design isn't good because of which the data retrieval is always slow.

Table 1: SystemsTable -- 2.2k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| Serial1    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Serial2    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ModelNum   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...        | ....         | ..   | 0   |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID & ModelNum. No Foreign Keys

Table 2: DetailTable1 -- 3.6k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id1        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Serial     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...        | ....         | ..   | 0   |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID1. No Foreign Keys

Table 3: LinkTable -- 6.9k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id1        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Id2        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Link       | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID1, ID2, Link. No Foreign Keys

Table 4: DetailTable2 -- 42k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id2        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Details    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...        | ....         | ..   | 0   |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID2. No Foreign Keys

**Idea:**

SystemsTable contains all the basic info by which user can search. EX: He can search by typing Model Number.

In order pick details from the DetailTable2,

1. I first pick `Serial1` & `Serial2` from `SystemsTable` compare with `DetailTable1`.
2. Pick all the matched `Id1`, iterate through them and pick matched `Id2` from
   `LinkTable`.
3. Match `Id2` from `LinkTable` with `Id2` from `DetailTable2` and finally display.

This is because none of the rows in DetailTable2 contains Serial number to match with.

Query1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM SystemsTable AS a, DetailTable1 AS b  
WHERE (b.Serial = a.serial1 OR  b.Serial = a.serial2) 
AND  a.model= 'ABC'
```

The result from above is iterated.

Query2:

```
for(DetailTable1 bean : tickets) {
        Query items= getSession().createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM" 
        + "DetailTable2 AS a, LinkTable AS b "
        + "where a.Id2 = b.Id2 AND b.Id1= :Id1");
        items.setParameter("Id1", bean.getID1());
}
```

There's definitely a better way to do this by changing Table design or code. Please give your suggestions to improve.

Comment: Learn how to use `JOIN`; it is soooo much faster than simulating it in application code as you showed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you have a `bigint(20)` defined as the PK of the first table and it appears that the corresponding field in the first detail table is `varchar(20)`. Most systems will perform the needed conversion behind the scenes, but converting takes resources.

Do you ever in your wildest dreams think you are going to create enough rows in the system table to get anywhere near filling a `bigint(20)` field? Would not an ordinary `int` do the job just as well?

Then you define all your serial number fields as `varchar(255)`. Really? Your serial numbers are alpha-numeric values up to 255 characters in length? I would like to see some of those serial numbers. Using varchar fields as key fields takes more time to search than numeric fields. That doesn't mean it should never be done -- just be aware of a little slower response time.

It's impossible to tell if your tables are properly normalized because of the generic field names and no explanation of what means what. Except, that is, for table1 and table3 which are not even in first normal form. Fixing that will give you quite a performance boost as you can define indexes that will actually work. I have a strong feeling that your four tables could be better designed as two or three tables which will result in simpler (and faster) queries. But there is not enough detail to make detailed suggestions.

Your queries look to be about as sound as could be expected, but both queries can definitely be combined into one to generate a list of final results for your loop.

Start by thinking about the entities you are modeling in your database and the domains of their attributes so to better select datatypes that best match those domains.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives quite a lot to work on, to boost the performance

I'm really not in a place to give up true columns that's why I've put it that way. The `Id` in the table1 with `bigint` is not related to any of the other Ids.

The serial numbers don't add up to 255 characters. Ex: 7Z90N59473

I'll work on Normalizing the tables but I'm sure how the queries can be combined. Maybe It's possible once the tables are normalized.

Comment: For now, I'm picking `Id1` from table2 by comparing the serials. Then, for each `Id1` I'm picking the linked `Id2` from the table3 and in turn selecting rows that match with the picked `Id2` from table4